# prevent sending message to unknown kafka topic when topic is defined programatically in Quarkus smallrye

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-reactive, smallrye-reactive-messaging, quarkus-kafka

I'm building a Quarkus service for being a middleware in charge of sending kafka events exposing a POST endpoint. As many other services use it, I have declared only one outgoing channel where topic is assigned programatically as below **emitter**

I want to apply any defensive mechanism to prevent pod keeps trying before get exhausted when topic name is wrong (currently pod tries like 6kish)

I tried different approaches setting up properties in application.yaml although none of them worked (retries, failure-strategy, health-topic-verification-enabled and so), as shown on below **yaml snippet**

Let me upload 2 screenshots , I have had to remove all matches for *UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}* on screenshot1 because otherwise I was not able to show you the whole flow

[image]

between above lines and even after than last line *testing NACK* there are 6k logs like below

[image]

**yaml snippet**

```
mp:
  messaging:
    outgoing:
      kafka-metrics:
        value:
          serializer: io.quarkus.kafka.client.serialization.ObjectMapperSerializer
        connector: smallrye-kafka
        merge: true

"%prod":
  quarkus:
    quartz:
      # Ensure tasks only run once even with multiple instances of the application running
      clustered: true
  mp:
    messaging:
      outgoing:
        kafka-metrics:
          retries: 5
          health-enabled: true
          health-topic-verification-enabled: true
          health-readiness-enabled: true
          failure-strategy: ignore
          health-readiness-topic-verification: true
          bootstrap:
            servers: ${DC_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
          security:
            protocol: SSL
          ssl:
            keystore:
              location: ${DC_KAFKA_KEYSTORE_LOCATION}
              password: ${DC_KAFKA_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
            truststore:
              location: ${DC_KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION}
```

**Emitter**

```
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Slf4j
    public class KafkaMetricsProducer implements MetricsProducer {
    private final Emitter<JsonNode> metricsMessageEmitter;

    public KafkaMetricsProducer(@Channel("kafka-metrics") Emitter<JsonNode> 
  metricsMessageEmitter) {
    this.metricsMessageEmitter = metricsMessageEmitter;
  }

  @Override
  @OnOverflow(OnOverflow.Strategy.DROP)
  public void send(GenericMetricEvent metric) {

    log.info(
        "Sending {} of schema version {} with key {} to {}",
        metric.getEventType(),
        metric.getSchemaVersion(),
        metric.getKey(),
        metric.getTopic());
    metricsMessageEmitter.send(
        Message.of(
                metric.getPayload(),
                () -> {
                  log.info("testing ACK logging");
                  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
                },
                reason -> {
                  log.info(
                      "testing NACK logging with failure reason cause {} , reason msg {}",
                      reason.getCause(),
                      reason.getMessage(),
                      reason.getStackTrace());

                  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
                })
            .addMetadata(
                OutgoingKafkaRecordMetadata.<String>builder()
                    .withTopic(metric.getTopic())
                    .withKey(metric.getKey())
                    .withTimestamp(Instant.now())
                    .withHeaders(
                        new RecordHeaders()
                            .add("schemaVersion", metric.getSchemaVersion().getBytes(UTF_8))
                            .add("messageId", MDC.get(DC_CORRELATION_ID_HEADER).getBytes(UTF_8))
                            .add("messageType", metric.getEventType().getBytes(UTF_8))
                            .add(
                                "eventTimestamp",
                                metric.getEventTimestamp().toString().getBytes(UTF_8)))
                    .build()));
    log.info(
        "Sent {} of schema version {} with key {} to {}",
        metric.getEventType(),
        metric.getSchemaVersion(),
        metric.getKey(),
        metric.getTopic());
  }
```